# Erro de "php.h not found" ao instalar extensão Intl no Mac

Tags: php, osx, symfony

Estou tendo problemas para instalar a extensão intl no Mac, já segui os seguintes tutoriais:

- [Installing Intl package on OSX Lion](http://darraghenright.tumblr.com/post/22027208929/installing-intl-package-on-osx-lion)
- [Install the PHP INTL extension on a Mac](https://gist.github.com/redefinelab/4188331)
- [Installing the PHP intl extension on OS X Mavericks](http://codingexplained.com/operating-systems/mac/installing-php-intl-extension-os-x-mavericks#comment-71009)

porém nos 3 eu travo no seguinte comando:

```
sudo pecl install intl
```

e recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.c:25:
/private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.h:23:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include <php.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Já tentei pesquisar sobre o específico erro mas não consegui encontrar uma resposta.

Alguém já passou pelo mesmo erro?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se isso te ajuda

Instale algumas dependências com *Homebrew:*

```
$ brew install autoconf
$ brew install icu4c 
$ brew link --force icu4c
```

Instale e verifique Pear/PECL ([fonte](http://techtastico.com/post/como-instalar-pear-y-pecl-en-os-x-mavericks)):

```
$ curl -O http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
  [ Select 1 and enter /usr/local/pear ]
  [ Select 4 and enter /usr/local/bin ]
  [ Press return ]
$ pear version
```

Instale PECL **intl**:

```
$ sudo pecl install intl
$ sudo cp /private/etc/php.ini{.default,}
$ sudo chmod 644 /private/etc/php.ini
$ echo extension=intl.so >> /private/etc/php.ini
```

Comment: segui os passos e chegando no comando sudo pecl install intl continua o erro citado, php.h not found.

Comment: tenta o brew install php55-intl

Comment: Olá Otto, recebo o seguinte erro: Error: No available formula for php55-intl

Comment: to tentando ajudar vou pesquisar um pouco mais aqui

Comment: você executou xcode-select –-install  ?

Comment: Também já @Otto, só que recebo o seguinte erro: xcode-select: error: invalid argument '–-install'. Obrigado pelo esforço até agora

Comment: @MarcoAntônioMafessolli: Não edite as respostas dos usuários para modificar algo que não tenha funcionado especificamente com você. Você até poderia complementar a resposta dada dizendo que "caso não funcione com X, pode-se tentar com Y", agregando informações, nunca substituindo (a menos que esteja REALMENTE errado)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode instalar o intl via Brew.

Utilize o comando: `brew install homebrew/php/php55-intl`

Answer (score 0):

Os `headers` do PHP não vem instalados no `Mojave`, se alguém estiver tendo este problema hoje, faça o seguinte:

> 1) Instala o xCoce CLT

```
xcode-select --install
```

> 2) Reinstala os arquivos headers:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```